# How to install .PRI printer definitions on SAP?

Tags: printing, sap-basis, system.printing

I'm trying to help a customer with SAP printing. I have the .PRI definition files from the printer Vendor. Where in SAP would the Printer definitions get loaded and/or configured?

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps:

1. Go to transaction `SPAD`
2. Press button "Full administration", then the number of available buttons will increase
3. Select tab "Device types"
4. Press "Display" button against the device type field and you will see the list of all the available device types in the system
5. There press edit button and then edit panel buttons will appear on the right which allow to add another type

[image]

6. After filling all mandatory fields go to this menu

[image]

and here it is

[image]